# Custom login route in Laravel

Tags: routes, laravel, laravel-4

How do i alter the default login route within Laravel as it seems to be defaulting to **/login** when i would like to be using **/account/signin** to keep my system catagorised.

Comment: there is no defualt login... but there is default login route name wich is 'login'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only one reference to a route 'login' in Laravel source code, but it is in your  `app/filters.php` file and this file is yours:

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('login');
});
```

So you can change it whenever you need to:

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('account/signin');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, completely forgot to look in their and instead looked everywhere else, haha.